a timer within a timer
hello and thank you in advance,
i'm currently coding The Cookie Cutter game from 100 Days of Code by Angela Yu,
the goal is to get as many clicks as possible within the span of 5 mins , while checking every 5 secs for the money (i called it "score") i've accumulated so i can purchase the highest available upgrade.
this is Angela's solution on Github:
i found it to be long and unnecessarily complicated.
my code is a bit messy as it's still a work in progress.
what i've been meaning to do with my code is to iterate through a directory that contains the #id and price of upgrade, and as soon as it recognizes a match for a possible purchase it clicks on it.
import threading
import time
from collections import defaultdict

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/")
driver.maximize_window()

#######################ELEMENTS & CONVERTING TO LISTS\DICT#######################
cookie = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cookie')
score = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#money')
scoreNum = int(score.text)
all_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#store b')
all_ids = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#store div')
new_all_prices = []
new_all_ids = []
for new_id in all_ids:
    new_all_ids.append(new_id.get_attribute("id"))
for price in all_prices:
    a, b, c = price.text.partition('-')
    new_price = c.replace(" ", "")
    if c == "":
        pass
    else:
        new_all_prices.append(c.replace(" ", ""))

tuples = [(key, value)
          for i, (key, value) in enumerate(zip(new_all_prices, new_all_ids))]

myDict = dict(tuples)

#######################FUNCTIONS#######################


def five_seconds_check():
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if scoreNum >= key:
            my_clickable_purchase = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'{myDict[key]}')
            my_clickable_purchase.click()


timeout = time.time() + 5
five_min = time.time() + 60 * 5  # 5 minutes

while True:
    cookie.click()
    if time.time() > timeout:
        five_seconds_check()
    elif time.time() > five_min:
        break

#########################CLOSING BROWSER#########################
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()


the part i'm struggling with is how to write a timer within a timer - meaning, how do i get the overall while loop to run for 5 mins, and simultaneously check the money\purchase upgrade every 5 secs.

just an aside but myDict = dict(zip(new_all_prices, new_all_ids)) should be enough

it is not clear what is your problem

"how do i get the overall while loop to run for 5 mins, and simultaneously check the money\purchase upgrade every 5 secs?" You have it loop every five seconds, and each time around the loop, you check to see how much time has elapsed since you started, and when the elapsed time gets to 5 minutes, you stop.

in case anyone is struggling with the same challenge or just wants to have a look - this is the final result after i've gotten some input and made more alterations to the overall code, as there were several things wrong with it except for the while loop.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/")
driver.maximize_window()

#######################ELEMENTS & CONVERTING TO LISTS\DICT#######################
cookie = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cookie')
all_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#store b')
all_ids = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#store div')
new_all_prices = []
new_all_ids = []
for new_id in all_ids:
    new_all_ids.append(new_id.get_attribute("id"))
for price in all_prices:
    a, b, c = price.text.partition('-')
    new_price = c.replace(" ", "")
    if c == "":
        pass
    else:
        new_all_prices.append(int(c.replace(" ", "").replace(",", "")))

tuples = [(key, value)
          for i, (key, value) in enumerate(zip(new_all_prices, new_all_ids))]


#######################FUNCTIONS#######################

def five_seconds_check():
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        score = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#money')
        scoreNum = int(score.text.replace(",", ""))
        if scoreNum >= key:
            my_clickable_purchase = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'#{value}')
            my_clickable_purchase.click()
            break


myDict = dict(tuples.__reversed__())

start_time = time.time()
timeout = start_time + 5
five_min = start_time + (60 * 5)  # 5 minutes

while time.time() < five_min:
    cookie.click()
    if time.time() >= timeout:
        five_seconds_check()
        timeout = time.time() + 5

#########################CLOSING BROWSER#########################
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()


I think you're pretty close! Just make sure your 5 second loop resets every time it finishes. Also, maybe store times as variables so you don't have to call time.time() so often.
I would also change that last elif to an if so you can run both the five-second loop and the five-minute break in the same iteration.
The completed code is as follows:
start_time = time.time()
timeout = start_time + 5
five_min = start_time + (60 * 5)  # 1 minutes

while True:
    cookie.click()
    curr_time = time.time()
    if curr_time > timeout:
        five_seconds_check()
        timeout = curr_time + 5
    if time.time() > five_min:
        break

There are other, more efficient ways of doing this as well, which don't rely on continuous while loops; consider looking into solutions centered around time.sleep() or the sched module.
